# Why might a Wordpress site have an /index.php/ rewrite rule?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I've just inherited a WP site to maintain, and every page on the site loads from

```
www.site.com/index.php/page
```

For what reason would a Wordpress site be set up like this? Can I possibly change this in the Dashboard, or would I need to modify htaccess?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Internally, all requests go through index.php. You can override this in the "Permalinks" section of your WP Admin Panel.